# CSS two same elements in inline-block one is lower than another

Tags: html, css

I have code this code in my HTML

```
<div class="project_box">
       <div class="img_wrapper">
        <img src="images/C.png" class="project_image">
       </div> 
       <span class="proj_title">Centill</span> 
       <span class="about_the_project">asaasjiasojasjoisaiojsaijasiojsaiojasiojasi</span> 
       <a href="http://centill.com/" target="_blank" class="project_link">Link</a> 
</div>
```

I have two of this elements except in second one `about_the_project`'s text is longer and because of that the first div is lower than the second one.You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/xf2batxm/ How can i make them appear on the same level?

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top` to the elements that have `display: inline-block`

Comment: @JonUleis thanks it worked